# MPAPI vs MPI.NET vs?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, parallel-processing

I'm working on college project. I have to develop distributed computing system. And i decided to do some research to make this task fun :)
I've found [MPAPI](http://mpapi.codeplex.com/) and [MPI.NET](http://www.osl.iu.edu/research/mpi.net/software/) libraries. Yes, they are .NET libraries(Mono, in my case). Why .NET ? I'm choosing between Ada, C++ and C# so to i've choosed C# because of lower development time.

I have two goals:

1. Simplicity;
2. Performance;
3. Cluster computing.

So, what to choose - [MPAPI](http://mpapi.codeplex.com/) or [MPI.NET](http://www.osl.iu.edu/research/mpi.net/software/) or [something else](http://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+parallel) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using .NET you could also use the windows HPC SDK
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=12887da1-9410-4a59-b903-693116bfd30e&displaylang=en

http://www.microsoft.com/hpc/en/us/default.aspx

But using Mono sounds like fun ;)

Comment: "windows HPC SDK" it's nice but i have no windows installed ;)

Comment: Just out of interest:
http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/06/01/microsoft_novell_hpc/